# How to select part of a list based on certain conditions

Tags: python, list, selection

I want to do the following:

```
L = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
new_list = list( element in L for i,j in L if i >1 and j >4)
```

the result of `new_list` will be `[(5,6)]`

I know how to do this for 1-d list, for instance:

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]

new_L1 = list( i for i in L1 if i>1 )
```

But I don't know how to do the similar for multi-dimensional lists in python.

Comment: Instead of `list(...)` use `[...]`. Yes, that works, and is called a list comprehension, and as a literal syntax is more efficient than your `list(..)` with a generator expression.

Comment: Curretly what I can do is the following: new_list = list( (i,j) for i,j in L if i>1 and j>4) but i feel the (i,j) part is clumsy, especially for a list with lots of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just unpack your nested tuples into your desired variables in the main loop:

```
[(i, j) for i, j in L if i > 1 and j > 4]
```

Note that you then do have to 'reconstruct' the original tuple in the left-hand-side expression.

Alternatively, address the elements with indices:

```
[elem for elem in L if elem[0] > 1 and elem[1] > 4]
```

Note that I used a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) here (you were using a *generator expression* inside the `list()` function, getting you similar results but in a less efficient manner).

Comment: The second method is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over the tuples normally:

```
new_l = [tup for tup in L if tup[0] > 1 and tup[1] > 4]
```